# How to get particular DataTable using TableName?

Tags: c#, datatable

One DataSet usually has lots of DataTable, but I'm only to target a particular DataTable which I thought it's pretty normal but apparently failed to do it?

 Below were the approaches I've tried:

```
//Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type.......
DataTable dt = from table in changesDataSet.Tables
               where table.TableName = "ABC"
               select table;

//Surprisingly there was no method "Where" in changesDataSet.Tables
DataTable dt = changesDataSet.Tables.Where(x=>x.TableName="ABC").First();
```

Below was the code that able to print each and every table. I know I can do it via a loop but please tell me loop isn't the only options

```
foreach(DataTable table in changesDataSet.Tables)
{
    Console.WriteLine(table.TableName);
}
```

Comment: `var dt = dataSet.Tables["something"];` is what you are looking for. But if for any reason you want to use linq, you can write query this way: `var dt = dataSet.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Where(x=>x.Name=="something").FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 5):

You can access the table using an indexer on the collection of tables ([DataTableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58st33fb(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
DataTable dt = changesDataSet.Tables["ABC"];
```